# Jaynes Cummigs model and Qutip

Tags: python, qutip

I have found in [Qutip manual](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxDFDYn-6Lc&t=606s) simple program for visualisation a periodic behaviour of JCM.

My code is

```
from qutip import *
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np

N=10
a=tensor(destroy(N),qeye(2))
sz=tensor(destroy(N),sigmaz())
s=tensor(qeye(N),destroy(2))
wc=wq=2*np.pi
g=np.pi
psi0=tensor(basis(N,0),basis(2,0))
H = wc*a.dag()*a-0.5*wq*sz+0.5*g*(a*s.dag()+a.dag()*s)
tlist=np.linspace(0,3,100)
out=mesolve(H,psi0,tlist,[],[a.dag()*a])
plot(tlist,out.expect[0])
plt.show()
```

And on the picture I should see there sinus line, but in this program I get only one narrow line. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the physics:
For an excited atom:

```
psi0=tensor(basis(N,0),basis(2,1))
```